# How Can Manage Dynamic Menu in React js using Strapi?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, strapi

I want to implement the Dynamic menu bar how can manage my menu, submenu or routing using strapi.

Comment: Good luck with that. What did you try? Where you are stuck at? Please provide a lot more information and don't expect things done for you.

Comment: You want to implement it in your administration panel or in your client application?

Comment: @soupette I want to as a client Application How can Manage Dynamic menu as well as the submenu.